# Bond CSST to Water Pipe - Allowed in 2017 NEC 250.104(B)?

Tags: pipe, gas, grounding-and-bonding, copper, csst

I am looking to bond out CSST gas line which is in our crawl space of the house (dirt floor) and the copper water pipe is close by. I was wondering if CSST can be bonded to the copper water pipe in Arkansas. I read through the 2017 NEC, specifically focusing on 250.104; however, I could not figure out a clear answer. I know that in some states, you are allowed to bond to the water system but I am specifically looking for Arkansas. Arkansas adopted the 2017 NEC with amendments on 1 Jan 18. Thank you.

Comment: Is your water pipe copper all the way to the street main? (i.e. is your water service line copper in addition to your indoor piping)

Comment: Also, is this CSST feeding any gas appliances that also use electricity?

Comment: Yes, the water service line is copper all the way (as far as I can tell). The CSST feeds the range which is also electric.   Also, I know I need to bond the piping (black metal piping) on the exterior of the house (there is already a bonding clamp, just no 6 gauge wire.. likely got broken). If there is the bonding wire outside the house next to the meter, does it need to also be bonded under the house where the black pipe goes to CSST? Thank you!

Comment: So do you think its okay to ground to water system?

Comment: Edited the answer -- hopefully that helps? In short, though, you can bond the black iron at the gas meter to a suitable bonding point, and that's *it*, you don't need to bond the CSST separately.  (You can't bond to a water system, though)

Answer (score 1):

### The gas system only needs to be bonded at one point

Bonding the black iron at the meter to a legal bonding point (anywhere on the grounding electrode system, basically, using a listed tap connector such as an ILSCO GTT-2-2 to connect the gas bond wire to the GEC, or simply by landing the gas bond wire on the intersystem bonding termination device if one is present) will suffice for bonding the entire gas system; there is no need for an extra bond point for the CSST if the system is already bonded, as per [this tech bulletin](http://www.csstsafety.com/Images/CSST-Direct-Bonding-Tech-Bulletin.pdf).

Or in short, simply connect the bonding wire at the meter to a suitable bonding point on the electrical system (not the water system, though!), as you don't have to worry about bonding the CSST separately.